# How to recovery message from signature? ethers.js

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js

*I'm not sure if I am conceptually wrong.*
I'm running some tests and trying to recover the text from a signed message.

```
it( "Should owner should be signer", async function ()
        {
            msg = "Hallo Welt";
            let signature = await owner.signMessage( msg );
            let signer = ethers.utils.verifyMessage( msg, signature );
            expect( signer ).to.equal( owner.address );
        } );
```

This is working fine, but I would like to do the other way around. Can I provide the signature and the signer retrieve the msg (Hello World). Couldn't find anything in the docs.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You indeed are conceptually wrong. You can't recover the text message.

You probably are misinterpreting the function of signatures in Ethereum. Signature are utilised to create a piece of data that proves that a particular address has signed a message, yet the message is required when verifying the signature.

You are probably looking for some sort of encryption.